# AngularJS: $filter 'date' won't change format

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to filter the current date into a format so that it can be accepted by my web API, the format being 01/01/0001 00:00:00.

Here is my attempted code at this -

```
    var today = Date();
    var completeDT = $filter('date')(today, 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

However completeDT will always hold something like "Tue Jul 14 2015 15:37:36 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)"

Can't seem to find an answer online, but I assume it is something fairly simple I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your today to this:

```
var today = new Date();
```

Comment: ugh, been a long day.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try:

```
var nowTemp = new Date();
        var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        var completeDT = $filter('date')(now,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM');
```

You ought to use new on Date.